# How to access, modify and validate values in a subclass, as a list

Tags: python, list, class

Pardon the subject line if it doesn't accurately describe what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure how else to describe it.

I have a class that contains a subclass. In the subclass there is a value that is a list. Using my main class, I want to be able to retrieve and set each individual value in that list. The code below is an example of what I'm trying to do and obviously does not work:

In this example I have a car. Every car will have four tires.  I want to be able to retrieve and set the type of tire on each wheel of my car individually. I also want validation to prevent me from putting an unwanted type of tire (Firestone) on my car.

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, model: str):

        self._model = model
        self._tires = self.Tires()

    class Tires():

        def __init__(self):

            # Default to no tires on the car
            self._tires = ["", "", "", ""]

# Create my car
my_car = Car("LeSabre")

# Put four tires on my car. I don't want Firestones, so it should error on the last two tires. How to validate???
my_car.Tires[0] = "Goodyear"
my_car.Tires[1] = "Goodyear"
my_car.Tires[2] = "Firestone"
my_car.Tires[3] = "Firestone"

# What is the second tire on my car?
print(my_car.Tires[1])
```

Comment: `Tires` is not a subclass, it's a nested class.

Comment: Which leads to the question, why is `Tires` nested inside `Car`?

Comment: did you run the posted code? `Car` class doesn't have `Tires` attribute...

Comment: You should not use nested classes like this - just pull your "class Tires" defintiion to top-level, and have a normal `self.tires = Tires()` attribute in the car class.  Python allows nesting classes, but this has no real use in O.O. programing - it can serve using the nested classes as namespaces, which is a completly different thing.

Comment: Thanks folks. That is the kind of info I'm looking for to help understand how I should be getting where I want to be.

Comment: @chepner Tires are only used on the Car object, so I thought that logically, it should be part of the Car class.

Comment: @jsbueno If Tires is only going to be used by a Car object, doesn't it make sense to make it a nested class? Or should I just not use a class for Tires at all?

Comment: @Calab let me put it this way, there is *practically never* a good reason to use a nested, so no, it doesn't make sense that it should be nested inside `Cars`. If you want to group logically related classes/functions together, that is what a *module* is for.

Comment: In languages like Java, it makes sense to have nested classes if you can definitively say that the nested class will never have any use, and it will never make sense for an instance of the nested class to exist without the top level class/instance. You could have `Citizenship` nested inside `Person`, because only people can be citizens of a country, and it will never make sense to have a `Citizenship` that doesn't belong to a `Person`. Python doesn't have that restriction, so you can instantiate your `Tires` class without a `Car` instance. So the main purpose of nested classes is defeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UserList` python library [list wrapper](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.UserList). Its items are stored in an underlying list in `data` attribute.

Modified source code:

```
import collections
from collections import UserList
class Car:

    def __init__(self, model: str):

        self._model = model
        self._tires = self.Tires()

    class Tires(UserList):

        def __init__(self):
            self.data = ["", "", "", ""]

my_car = Car("LeSabre")

my_car._tires[0] = "Goodyear"
my_car._tires[1] = "Goodyear"
my_car._tires[2] = "Firestone"
my_car._tires[3] = "Firestone"

print(my_car._tires[1])
```

prints `Goodyear`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the comments. It helped me get my head around what I was trying to do. This is what I came up with. It might not be the best, or prettiest, but it works...

I am definitely open to comments on this code.

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, model: str):

        self._model = model
        self._tires = ["", "", "", ""]

    def tires(self, tires: list = None) -> list:
        """

        :param tires: A list of four tires to put on the car

        :return: A list of tires on the car
        """

        # If we specified some tires...
        if tires is not None:
            # ... there must be 4 of them
            if len(tires) != 4:
                raise Exception("Wrong number of tires for a car")

            # Change all four tires
            for t in range(0, 4):
                self.tire(t, brand=tires[t])

        return self._tires

    def tire(self, index:int, brand: str = None):
        """

        :param self:
        :param index: Which tire are we accessing
        :param brand: What brand of tire are we putting on

        :return: The brand of tire at that index
        """

        # There can only be four tires
        if index < 0 or index > 3:
                raise Exception("Invalid tire selected")

        if brand is not None:
            # Make sure they don't put a Firestone on my car
            if brand == "Firestone":
                    raise Exception("Don't use Firestone tires")
            else:
                self._tires[index] = brand

        return self._tires[index]

# Create my car
my_car = Car("LeSabre")

# Put four tires on my car. I don't want Firestones, so it should error on the last two tires. How to validate???
my_car.tire(0, "Goodyear")
my_car.tire(1, "Goodyear")
my_car.tire(2, "Uniroyal")
my_car.tire(3, "Uniroyal")

# What is the third tire on my car?
print(my_car.tire(2))
# What are all the tires on my car?
print(my_car.tires())
# Put a Firestone on my car
my_car.tire(1, "Firestone")
```